# Ruby and math module to solve trig functions

Tags: ruby, math, equation-solving

So I'm trying to practice using Ruby to solve trig functions and I'm having some difficulty getting the Math library to work.

The trig function is: `y = (x^3 sqrt(2x^2)) / (sin(x+5))` where x = 51, and the answer needs to be in degrees. The problem is supposed to be solved in Matlab, which I have no experience with, but I managed to hack together the following output for the function: `1.1540e + 07`, and I want to verify that what I'm doing in Matlab is correct, so I want to use Ruby to make sure the answer is what I'm supposed to be getting.

The Ruby code I'm trying to use to solve this function is: `puts ((51 ** 3)Math.sqrt(2(51 ** 2)) / (Math::sin(56.degrees)))` however when running the code I get the following errors:

```
/Users/sam/Desktop/jasons_shit.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')'
puts ((51 ** 3)Math.sqrt(2(51 ** 2)) / (Math::sin(56.degrees)))
                   ^
/Users/sam/Desktop/jasons_shit.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
puts ((51 ** 3)Math.sqrt(2(51 ** 2)) / (Math::sin(56.degrees)))
                           ^
/Users/sam/Desktop/jasons_shit.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
puts ((51 ** 3)Math.sqrt(2(51 ** 2)) / (Math::sin(56.degrees)))
```

How can I go about evaluating this function and resolving the errors?

Comment: Is this a matlab or a ruby question?

Comment: @NKN Ruby. I want to double check the answer I got out of Matlab using Ruby's Math functions.

Comment: @NKN and I don't know what's up with the errors I'm getting using Ruby's Math library

Comment: Is it possible that you need to add `*` where you want to multiply? As in: `puts ((51 ** 3)*Math.sqrt(2*(51 ** 2)) / (Math::sin(56.degrees)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have * each time you multiply, and try changing degrees to radians:

```
x = 51
p (x ** 3) * Math.sqrt(2 * x ** 2) / (Math::sin((x+5) * Math::PI / 180))
```

You also don't need so many paranthesis because Ruby understands mathematical order of operations.

Answer (score 1):

As the error is telling you, some `(` and `*` are missing.

Since the intended variable should be in Radians, so you should convert first to from degrees to radians and then do the calculation.

```
xindeg = 51
xinrad = xindeg*Math::PI/180
puts xinrad ** 3 * Math.sqrt(2*xinrad ** 2) / Math::sin(xinrad+5*Math::PI/180)

1.070855715686936
```

Also in MATLAB, the correct way is as follows:

```
x=51
xinrad = x*pi/180;
y = (xinrad^3 * sqrt(2*xinrad^2)) / (sin(xinrad+5*pi/180))

y =

1.070855715686936
```